# Structuring controllers to submit a form in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I'm learning `Codeigniter` and I have a controller named `Admin` controller

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller{

/* skipped */

//This function is used to generate changepassword form
public function changepassword(){

    $this->data['sessiondata'] = $_SESSION['logged_in'];
    $this->data['mainview'] = 'components/admin/changepassword';
    $this->load->view($this->layout, $this->data);

}


//changepassword form will be submitted to this function ('admin/checkpassword')
public function checkpassword(){

    $error = array(
        'required' => '%s tidak boleh kosong',
        'matches' => '%s tidak sama, dumb ass'
    );

    /* some validations skipped */

    if($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE){
        $this->data['mainview'] = 'components/admin/changepassword';
        $this->load->view($this->layout, $this->data);  

    } else {

        $tobesent = array(
            "oldpassword" => $this->input->post('oldpassword'),
            "newpassword" => $this->input->post('newpassword'),
            "verifynewpasswprd" => $this->input->post('verifynewpassword')
        );

        $this->admincrud->changepassword($tobesent);

        $this->data['result']   = "Password sukses diubah";
        $this->data['mainview'] = 'components/admin/changepassword';
        $this->load->view($this->layout, $this->data);

    }

}

}
```

the result is, each time I go to `base_url('admin/changepassword')`, fill the provided form and then submit the form, my url changes from `base_url('admin/changepassword')` into `base_url('admin/checkpassword')`, which I know came as the result of submitting the form. Also each time I `type base_url('admin/checkpassword')` directly on my address bar, it opens the form, which I know came as the result of the if-else condition in `checkpassword` function. My question is, from the security standpoint, is it okay if I keep using this structure? and how can I prevent users from directly accessing `base-url('admin/checkpassword')` and instead redirecting them to `base_url('admin/changepassword')` ?

Comment: You can check if user is login in the constructer of your admin controller.

Comment: couldn't understand. Could you point me some examples @Drudge ?

Comment: Actually, i am not clear with you question . Are the view same for both method?

Comment: change password function loads the change password form, check password function processes the submitted form from change password function. They are both built in the same class.

Comment: i know they are built in the same class . My question is "Do they(function) load the same view ?? "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if you don't want the URL to be changed after submitting the form.

You can use `redirect('admin/changepassword');` and since you need to provide 
messages accordingly, you can use `$this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Your message');` before redirection and use it in view like this:
`<?php if($this->session->flashdata('msg') <> NULL){echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');} ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your problem is `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` if i understood correctly...

For example :-

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')//form method is post
{
  //checkpassword code
}
else
{
  redirect(base_url('admin/changepassword'));
}
```